# Relative speed of trains moving in same direction

Tags: soft-question

I came across a formula that "Two trains moving in the same direction at x m/s and y m/s, (x>y)
then their relative speed is (x-y) m/s " . But isn't this a speed of faster train compared to slower one? For slower train isn't the speed should be (y-x) m/s? As a person in slower train will experience going backwards.

Please correct me.

Comment: Yes, but $(y-x)=-(x-y)$. The magnitude of the speed is the same but the two vectors have opposite directions.